# JavaScript toLocaleTimeString() - does not work properly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Today I've encountered a problem with dates in JavaScript
I'm trying to display time is format: hour:minute. To do this i've written a test case:

```
var timeOpts = {hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit"};
var dt = new Date('2014-05-08T16:07:51+00:00');
console.log(dt.toLocaleTimeString('uk-UA',timeOpts))
```

This code works just fine in Chromium (displays 19:07) but in Firefox it does not output time in right format (displays 19:07:51)

Comment: What version of Chromium and Firefox are you using?

Comment: Chromium 27.0.1441.0 (188246), Firefox 28

Comment: Works for me in Firefox Nightly on Linux.

Comment: Firefox Nightly - its good for development but not for production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concerned about formatting dates correctly across several major browsers, I would go with [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). You can format dates how you want and not worry about browser implementations of toLocaleTimeString(). If you want the format `HH:mm`, you would use this code:

```
var dt = new Date('2014-05-08T16:07:51+00:00');
var locale = moment(dt).format("HH:mm");
console.log(locale);
```

You may think that using Moment.js is a little more than you need, but it really is quite lightweight and it handles all the nitty gritty date manipulations for you and will take into effect browser differences and implementations.